# Can I use Zabbix for monitoring JSON log files generated by my application?

Tags: logging, monitoring, zabbix, logfile-analysis, zabbix-api

We have Zabbix server and Zabbix agent installed on different machines and we are able to monitor the infrastructure, but we also want to monitor the JSON log files generated by our application and to get notify if there is any error in logs and also it would be great if we can query on those logs from Zabbix UI.
So I want to know if this is possible using Zabbix and if yes, then any useful links are appreciated.

Comment: you are probably looking for this https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items

Comment: @IronBishop Thanks for the response, I tried the mentioned process but I got no success.  I could not even get the logs on my UI. Does this work for files in JSON format and .json extension?

Comment: Works for every text file with lines. Doesn't matter the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching screens how I monitor some logfile.

Item config here:
[image]

Trigger config here:
[image]

also agree with @Iron Bishop - you should take a look at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items